# Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 under Xcode IONIC IOS App

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am building an application for IOS using the IONIC framework. It was working fine, that is, until I added this plugin [cordova-plugin-firebase-analyticsHowever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics). Now, I keep getting the following error:

`ld: 89 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have read the similar questions posted here but none of solutions worked. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Found this on github https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12942#issuecomment-330893199

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already tried this and it won't work.